# Recommendations for custom string comparison

Tags: javascript, string, comparator

I'm building a code course platform. The users have a doc on the right side of his screen and an interactive IDE to practice on the left. The code verification is done by checking if the user's answer (his overall code compacted in one string) contains all the requirements (several "mandatory" strings).

The platform works well except for one point, this logics is not flexible. For example:

`this.variable='test'` wouldn't be accepted if the expected answer was `this.variable = "test";`.

This is only a problem of double/single quotes, spaces and semi-colon.

So I would like to know what would be the best option.. Creating a custom `indexOf()` function that would exclude space&semi-colon and consider single and double quote as the same thing? Or maybe a dedicated library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: normalize

Replace every ambiguous tokens, and remove withespaces and semicolons

```js
const input = `this.variable='test'`
const expected = `this.variable = "test";`

const normalize = (str) => str.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/(\s|;)/g, '').replace(/\"/g, '\'')

console.log(normalize(input));
console.log(normalize(expected));
console.log(normalize(input) === normalize(expected))
```

### Option 2: semantic analysis

You can use a tool like [esprima](https://esprima.org/) to analyse the user input, then compare it to what you expect:

```js
var esprima = require('esprima');
const input = `this.variable='test'`

console.log(esprima.tokenize(input));

// [
//     { type: 'Keyword', value: 'this' },
//     { type: 'Punctuator', value: '.' },
//     { type: 'Identifier', value: 'variable' },
//     { type: 'Punctuator', value: '=' },
//     { type: 'String', value: "'test'" }
// ]

console.log(esprima.parse(input));

// {
//     "type": "Program",
//     "body": [
//         {
//             "type": "ExpressionStatement",
//             "expression": {
//                 "type": "AssignmentExpression",
//                 "operator": "=",
//                 "left": {
//                     "type": "MemberExpression",
//                     "computed": false,
//                     "object": {
//                         "type": "ThisExpression"
//                     },
//                     "property": {
//                         "type": "Identifier",
//                         "name": "variable"
//                     }
//                 },
//                 "right": {
//                     "type": "Literal",
//                     "value": "test",
//                     "raw": "'test'"
//                 }
//             }
//         }
//     ],
//     "sourceType": "script"
// }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I needed